# hudson git https password, how do I specify it?

Tags: git, jenkins, hudson

When using the hudson git plugin with https, how to I specify a password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. It is bug in git plugin, but there is fork that fixes it, see:

http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-3807

Comment: link's broken nowadays - I wonder what information did it contain.

Comment: See that in the Wayback Machine for [HUDSON-3807](https://web.archive.org/web/20130313085902/http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-3807), and [HUDSON-7091]() and [HUDSON-7346]() too, while you're at it. Typical tail-chasing, "Cannot reproduce" and environment creep.

Comment: That is, [HUDSON-7091](https://web.archive.org/web/20101229120324/http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-7091) and [HUDSON-7346](https://web.archive.org/web/20101011024758/http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-7346) too, while you're at it. I am working around with [Git credential.helper functionality](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials/1.8.2.1), and forcing the master server to [use native Git CLI](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20261)

Answer (score 24):

The status as of this writing is that you can.

There are at least two ways of doing it:

1. specifying it in the url (https://user:pass@yourdomain.com/yourrepo)
2. specifying it in .netrc  file for the user env that is running the Hudson build (_netrc on windows)

netrc approach is by default a plain text file. If needed, it can be encrypted as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github/18362082#18362082), or just be readable for that one user through permissions.

Comment: Useful answer; [this post](http://dustint.com/post/299/hudson-jenkins-and-git-http-authentication) has more details on how to achieve this on Linux and Windows

Comment: First answer where I saw someone put the username/password in the url. Thanks.

Comment: I also forgot that option #1 is possible. . . dirty, but works for me.

Comment: specifying in the url as above worked for me - thanks