# How do I setup Git version control on Jenkins (on Windows)

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

I've been going round in circles for the past day attempting to get this working. I have found numerous instructions on how I might set this up but haven't progressed that far...

- I have no previous experience with Git and I think many of these guides make an assumption that you have some basic understanding of Git
- Many Windows specific guides talk about Jenkins running as the system user - that isn't the case for me, I just dropped the WAR into Tomcat and started it up

**What I have done:**

- I have installed the [Git Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) (and upgraded some of its plugin dependencies).
- I have started following the 'instructions' on the plugin's page (and got highly confused and feel that possibly some steps are irrelevant for me)
- Started following the steps described [here](http://computercamp.cdwilson.us/jenkins-git-clone-via-ssh-on-windows-7-x64) - I fall over fairly soon when it asks me to set my Jenkins path to *cmd/git.cmd* (I only have a *cmd/git.exe* in that directory). Nevertheless I struggle on, until it starts talking about SSH keys and the system user, well I don't have an issue with users I don't think.
- I did take a look at Git password caching (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)), but the cached credentials still timeout which isn't ideal for the Jenkins user.
- I tried to get up to speed with Git and it's access protocols using this [guide](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

**Current errors:**

Given that I have no username or password yet configured, it comes as no surprise that with my Git configured Jenkins job throws the following error:

```
Cloning repository https://git.company.local/scm/project.git
git --version
git version 1.8.4.msysgit.0
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone https://git.company.local/scm/project.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone https://git.company.local/scm/project.git
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:285)
    ...
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to connect to https://git.company.local/scm/project.git (status = 401)
    ...
    ... 16 more
Trying next repository
ERROR: Could not clone repository
java.io.IOException: Could not clone
```

**What I want to achieve:**

I have a Git repository in [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview) using a *https* protocol. I don't believe it is currently setup for SSH. I had assumed I could just enter the username and password in the Jenkins' job configuration and be done with it, just like other SCM configuraiton sections, but no.

I do not want my Jenkins' Git password stored in plain text in the job's configuration section i.e. in the URL.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You don't want your Jenkins's git credentials in plain text? That is why I wrote http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309 ;)

Comment: Long question, but isn't this a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363606/hudson-git-https-password-how-do-i-specify-it), with the addition of answer to use encryption provided by VonC. So, if you don't want to use something showing in the job config, use _netrc or encryption as explained by VonC.

Comment: Also, if cache expiry is your only problem with credential helper, you should probably just use `git config credential.helper store` which was already explained in the thread you linked to. That doesn't expire.