# Pull from bitbucket in Jenkins to run cucumber

Tags: git, bash, jenkins

I have a cucumber repository "tests" in bitbucket.

I configure the Jenkins server like this:

[image]

But I got an error like this:

```
> git pull origin develop 
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://aaa@bitbucket.org': Invalid argument
```

What should I do?

Thx

Comment: Since you can't authenticate through HTTPS username/password in a batch script, you should probably use SSH instead and configure key authentication. See documentation: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

Comment: why not use the jenkins scm for git pull ? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

Comment: @4ae1e1 sure you can, though I wouldn't recommend doing so. ssh is clearly a better option.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I did. I commented that you're wrong about https authentication through batch script not being possible, but I agree that SSH would be better anyway.

Comment: @eis I see. Just curious, how is it possible? HTTP Basic Authentication?

Comment: @4ae1e1 http://stackoverflow.com/a/9786186/365237

Comment: @eis Thanks for the pointer. #1 is HTTP Basic Authentication and I'd never put my password in clear text... #2 (`.netrc`) is new to me.

Comment: (ah, meant to say earlier that I did reply to right guy, not the wrong one...can't edit it anymore)